# Rewrite rule & escaping (encoded) forward slashes within URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have developed this RewriteRule which has been working great, up until I discovered an issue.

This is the rule here:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/%2/%4.php -f
 RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%4.php?id=%3 [QSA,L]
```

The URL format is like so:   /home/service/*ID*/scriptname
note that *ID* is dynamic and the RewriteRule does not take not of it when checking for the files existence.

But in this one scenario I found out, one of the IDs I'm using contains a '%2F' - which when decoded is translated to a forward slash (/) - And for some reason, the Rewrite rule when breaks because it thinks there's another directory.

My question is, why is %2F being decoded within the RewriteRule, and how can I engineer a solution? - Preferably other than a quick hack or changing the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the **B** flag in the rewrite rule, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%4.php?id=%3 [QSA,L,B]
```

Check this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) for more information.

Comment: The issue with that is, %4 can sometimes have child directories, it could be /scriptname or it could be /scriptname/child/bacon :(
That is pretty much what I need though, but only to apply to one variable somehow.

Comment: Can't think of anything as the flags are applied to the whole substitution URL, but have you tried it and the result is not as expected?

Comment: Correct :( - I found my fix outside mod_rewrite, it's all good now.
Basically modified the Encrypt and Decrypt (which the IDs are based off) to alter the forward slash character to another which was not in the character index map of the encryption.  Thanks for your answer though :) I'll mark it as answered because theoretically, that is correct.