# .htaccess rule ignored when % mark is present

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule:

RewriteRule ^places/([^/]+)$ PlaceD.php?LF=F&LFC=Place&PlaceID=$1

But when i call a URL as follows (when % mark is there) it is ignored:

```
http://mydomain/places/sri-maha-bhodi-%2F-bodiya
```

But following works (Without % mark):

```
http://mydomain/places/sri-maha-bhodi-2F-bodiya
```

How should i change the rewrite rule please?

Comment: %2F is really a big problem, try to avoid it appearing in url if you can. To solve this, add "AllowEncodedSlashes on" in httpd.conf(not in .htaccess), and change ([^/]+) to (.+) in RewriteRule.

Comment: Very helpful comment by @Andrew but better to use `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode` for security reasons. [Read more about it here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes)

Answer (score 0):

Apache may be encoding the %2F, which then doesn't match the RewriteRule. There's a few things going on here, but the basic is that forward slashes aren't allowed to be passed encoded in the url.  In order to make this work, you'll need to set `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode`.  This can't be done in an .htaccess file, and must be done in the config.  You may also need to set another flag in the Rewrite Rule.

```
RewriteRule ^places/([^/]+)$ PlaceD.php?LF=F&LFC=Place&PlaceID=$1 [B]
```

Sources:
[Rewrite rule & escaping (encoded) forward slashes within URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497333/rewrite-rule-escaping-encoded-forward-slashes-within-url)
[AllowEncodedSlashes Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes)
[B (escape backreferences)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But it doesn't work :( Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Added additional information and possibly another way to handle this.  Sad news, is if you can't update the config file, you may not be able to handle encoded forward slashes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your update and time. But sadly i can't update the config file. So i ended up removing all the forward slashes from place names.